# jQuery OR selector for multiple IDs

Tags: jquery

I am trying to validate a form with multiple ID selectors but doesn't seem to work.
what am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input:text:first").focus();
 $("form").submit(function(){
     if($("#sku").val()==""){
     alert('SKU NEEDED!');
     return false;
     }
     if($('#cost,#exp').val()==""){
         alert('At least one shipping cost is required!');
         return false;
         }
```

});
});

I am trying to test if #cost OR #exp do not have any value in them yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `if($('#cost,#exp').val()==""){`, use:

```
if($('#cost').val()=="" || $('#exp').val()==""){
```

When getting a value, [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) only gets the "value of the first element in the set of matched elements", so you can't combine the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Following syntax is valid

```
 if($('#cost').val()=="" || $('#exp'.val()=="")){
     alert('At least one shipping cost is required!');
     return false;
  }
```

as you can take value of one id at a time.So better approach to avoid confusion and clean code  , you can cache values in variable ,so its is even easy to read,understand.

```
 var costVal=$('#cost').val();
 var expVal=$('#exp'.val();

 if(costVal=="" || expVal=="")){
     alert('At least one shipping cost is required!');
     return false;
  }
```